# symfony2 cygwin cli php commands error

Tags: php, symfony, cygwin

When I try to run a symfony console php command (generate:bundle, etc) in cygwin, I get an error similar to:

> > [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ContextErrorException]
> >       Warning: file_get_contents(E:/xampp/htdocs/foo_com/app/config/parameters.yml): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /cygdrive/e/xampp/htdocs/foo_com/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Yaml/Yaml.php line 61

If I delete the app/cache folder, I can run the app/console commands without any issues, until I access my page in the browser. Once I access my page in the browser I start to get this error again.

Answer (score 1):

Try to do the following:
(assuming that you run windows 7):

- run `cygwin\bin\dash.exe` as administrator
- `/usr/bin/rebaseall -v`
- run `cygwin.bat` as administrator

In my case it solved this problem.